# pdftexcmds error: wrong lua module

Tags: texlive, lua, tlmgr

I just did a clean install from `texlive`, I updated every package with `tlmgr` and I get this error when trying to run `lualatex`:

```
! Package pdftexcmds Error: Wrong version of lua module.
(pdftexcmds)                Package version: 2019/11/24 v0.31
(pdftexcmds)                Lua module: 2019/07/25 v0.30.
```

I have no idea how to fix this.

**edit**:

```
kpsewhich -all pdftexcmds.lua
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.lua
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.lua
```

Comment: what does `kpsewhich -all pdftexcmds.lua` report? the first listed file should have a 2019/11/24 date if you look in it.

Comment: it should be `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.lua`  you probably have a local copy under `something/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.lua`, I would guess

Comment: how did that get there I wonder?

Comment: should I delete the oberdiek version?

Comment: yes but tlmgr should have done that. So that indicates a problem somewhere.

Comment: the oberdiek location was the correct location until this week, I moved it to a separate pdftexcmds ctan update split off from oberdiek,

Comment: I just asked in chat and other people all report the update went smoothly and the old one was deleted automatically. Did you get any warnings? (in particular do you have normal write permissions for the file?)

Comment: should I delete the entire oberdiek folder or just the pdftexcmds.lua? I don't recall any errors to be honest. but of course what happened is that I didn't have lualatex and the machine and assumed I didn't have tex and just got the latest texlive. I might have actually had tex and somehow that messed it up, even though it is not too likely. I was not paying much attention since it's nothing complicated usually :)

Comment: What do you get if you run `tlmgr update --list`. Does it mention oberdiek somewhere?

Comment: just  remove the one file. (or try `tlmgr install --reinstall oberdiek` might be safer

Comment: No it doesn't. For ` tlmgr reinstall oberdiek` I get `unknown action`.

Comment: sorry I edited the comment I got the reinstall incantation wrong:-)

Comment: ok :) I did the reinstall, and still update --list doesn't report oberdiek and kpsewhich reports both. I am using sudo and I ticked the make symlinks option during install. Just to be very specific :)

Comment: (I can also just delete the file, but if you need some debug info I can leave it around like this until tomorrow and do this and that)

Comment: I can't really debug, I just upload the new packages to ctan the tlmgr config is handled by the texlive maintainers. But it's odd it just fails for you. It may be that your mirror hasn't fully updated and has the new pdftexcmds but still has the old oberdiek (in which case it will fix itself tomorrow)  I'd just delete the file and check if you get an oberdiek update in the next day or so

Comment: The question was not if oberdiek is in the list, but if tlmgr reports something like "ignoring oberdiek".

Comment: Ok, I'll just delete it then. I just grepped oberdiek and no result. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
kpsewhich -all pdftexcmds.lua
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.lua
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.lua
```

indicates that the `tlmgr update` did not update completely, the old (last week's) location  `oberdiek/pdftexcmds.lua` should have been deleted as the new separated `pdftexcmds` tlmgr package was installed.

Or.. to put it another way

```
tlmgr update pdftexcmds
```

should have installed the new one but

```
tlmgr update oberdiek
```

should have effectively removed the old one, and

```
tlmgr update --all
```

should have done both of these.